# Excel Group of image hiding on another sheet checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to hide a bunch of images i have placed into a group via a checkbox, I can do this via the same sheet but no on the sheet the textbox is.

```
Sub hideimages()
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 21").Visible = True
        Else: ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 21").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

But i can't seem to figure out the right syntax to get it to affect another sheet for the group I can do it for a singular image:

```
Sub CheckBox33_Click()
Dim obj As Shape
Set obj = Worksheets("sheet3").Shapes("picture 2")
If obj.Visible Then
    obj.Visible = True
Else
    obj.Visible = False
End If
```

How could i merge these? the ways i have tried are not happy!

```
Sub hidaway()
    If Worksheets("sheet1").CheckBoxes("Check Box 34").Value = 1 Then
        Worksheets("sheet3").group("Group 21").Visible = True
        Else: Worksheets("sheet3").group("Group 21").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I would switch out `Activesheet` with the sheet you expect that checkbox to run on.  Otherwise, if the sheet changes, the `ActiveSheet` will be that new one.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I've changed activesheet to the sheet name now but still can't seem to figure out how to get the group to work as expected

Comment: Just to confirm, your checkbox is on a tab named `sheet1` and your group is on a tab named `sheet3`?

Comment: Hi JNevill that's correct!

Comment: Can confirm that the group name `group 21` and the checkbox  name `Check Box 34` didn't change when you moved them to the other tabs (Not sure which one moved). Do you get any errors when this subroutine runs?

Comment: Hi, Yes none have moved just changed the code, i get run time '438' object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkbox returns True/False so you just need to feed this value to your group visible property:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Shapes("Group 21").Visible = Me.CheckBox1.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Darren, that makes sence but i can;t seem to get it to pass, your code seems to give me an error about an invalid use of a Me keyword, do i need to set this as soemthing?

Comment: The `Me` keyword would be valid inside the worksheet module in this instance - thought that `Sub CheckBox33_Click()` was inside there.  I tried changing `Me` to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` which picks up the correct value, but wasn't hiding the group.  Try changing the tick box to an `ActiveX Control` - right click it and select view code.  Paste the code in there.